# How to get DB object in SailsJS / Waterline adapter methods?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, orientdb, waterline, nosql

I am trying to write a [SailsJS](http://sailsjs.org/) / [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) adapter for [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/) using [Oriento](https://github.com/codemix/oriento) module for NodeJS.

I am able to understand the basics of Waterline adapter interface using [boilerplate adapter code for SailsJS](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-adapter-boilerplate) but not sure how to get hold of DB object in adapter methods. I am sure DB object is created and maintained by SailsJS or Waterline but how to get an access to it in adapter's methods as without DB object, I will not be able to make call to OrientDB. Look for code samples in [Oriento](https://github.com/codemix/oriento) module to know how to call OrientDB from NodeJS.

I will appreciate if some one can show some example code of getting DB object in adapter's method - define(), describe(), drop(), find() etc.

Comment: I am unaware of a public OrientDB adapter that works with SailsJS and Waterline. Is this something you're still working on?

Comment: Here is the [SailsJS adapter for OrientDB](https://github.com/gauravdhiman/sails-orientdb-binary) that I developed. Feel free to extent it and share feedback. Link - https://github.com/gauravdhiman/sails-orientdb-binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're unfamiliar with Sails, but looks like the `_dbPools` private variable is what you're looking for - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-adapter-boilerplate/blob/master/index.js#L59